# How to find where an instance variable of some object is set to some concrete value?

Tags: decompilation, ghidra

I have a binary which implements license restrictions for concurrent users to a hard-coded value of 4. For various reasons I need to increase that hard-coded value, but am unable to build the app on my own. So I thought it was fastest to have a look at Ghidra if I find the assignment of the hard-coded value and can simply change that using some HEX editor or within Ghidra or something like that. The following is the source code I'm interested in:

```pascal
procedure TDataMod.dm_ButWeldCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  s              :string;
////*******************************************************
const
{$IFDEF _RSC_DATABASE_SYBASE_}
 dbdef          :TStdDBResource=(dbn:'[...]';user:'[...]';passw:'[...]') ;
{$ENDIF}
{$IFDEF _RSC_DATABASE_MSSQL_}
  {$IFDEF _SECURE_PASSWORD_}
    dbdef          :TStdDBResource=(dbn:'[...]';user:'[...]';passw:'[...]');     // 2012-01-04
  {$ELSE}
    dbdef          :TStdDBResource=(dbn:'[...]';user:'[...]';passw:'[...]');
  {$ENDIF}
{$ENDIF}
{$IFDEF _RSC_DATABASE_INTERBASE_}
 dbdef          :TStdDBResource=(dbn:'[...]';user:'[...]';passw:'[...]') ;
{$ENDIF}
begin
{$IFDEF _RSC_USE_USERS_LIMIT_}
(*
  {$IFDEF _CUSTOMER_LIEBHERR_}
    rscDBFramework.MaxUsers:=3;
    db_Butweld.rscMaxUsers:=3;
  {$ELSE}
      {$IFDEF _CUSTOMER_BV_}
        rscDBFramework.MaxUsers:=3;
        db_Butweld.rscMaxUsers:=3;
      {$ELSE}
        rscDBFramework.MaxUsers:=5;
        db_Butweld.rscMaxUsers:=5;
      {$ENDIF}
  {$ENDIF}
*)

 db_Butweld.rscMaxUsers:=4;
 rscDBFramework.MaxUsers:=4;
{$ELSE}
 db_Butweld.rscMaxUsers:=0;
 rscDBFramework.MaxUsers:=0;
{$ENDIF}
```

And the assignments of the following two lines is what I need to change:

```pascal
db_Butweld.rscMaxUsers:=4;
rscDBFramework.MaxUsers:=4;
```

The problem is I can't find those assignments. I've searched for functions using that value, found them and tried to go upwards until some data structure or stuff looks like what I need. But what I find looks like the following and I can't make sense of that:

[image: screenshot data structure]

So I tried a different approach using hard-coded strings to access the database, because some of those are pretty unique. Found those as well, but am unable to find the places where those strings are used in the end, which I hoped was the same place like where the assignments of interest happen. All I find is some string table or something, but I can't find anybody using the entry of interest in that table.

Some random screenshots of what I found as well, but is a dead-end to me:

[image: Resources of TDataMod]

[image: TDataMod String 01]

[image: TDataMod String 02]

**Is there any good approach to find the assignments I'm interested in?**

Comment: That's Delphi, right? Try searching the binary's strings for `TDataMod`. You might find RTTI for the class in question, which could make it easier to locate its methods.

Comment: Yes and tried that as well already, but only find strings, some resources etc. Nothing I can make use of. TDataMod seems to contain `db_Butweld` and `rscDBFramework` as properties, doesn't it? How would that look like in RTTI?

Comment: I need to find the code of `dm_ButWeldCreate` using some unique search term or alike. I find some string with that value, but it's a dead-end, I don't see where it's used or which function belongs to that.

Comment: @ThorstenSchöning you have the source, right? Something must be using these values (otherwise they wouldn't be of concern). Can you find that code perhaps? It's really tough to help without even having a binary at hand, that's the issue.

Comment: Depending on the exact binary it could also be worthwhile to use a tool such as WinDbg or x64dbg for dynamic analysis rather than static analysis. Unfortunately `4` is a value that will be found all over the place usually. However, even searching for the immediate value 4 could be promising in your case. For starters (as Rolf pointed out) the RTTI has the type name in string form and the "field" your code accesses will be in the vicinity of that. But there could still be loads of accesses with the immediate value `4`. Thus it may make sense to correlate the source code ...

Comment: In case you can give more info and are fine with chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7992/reverse-engineering